# Horizontal ScrollView in html page with ViewPager

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I have a Custom Horizontal Scroll View in a Html page , now this horizontal scrolling based on java script library , now when i load the html pager in a webview i cant scroll horizontally because the viewpager take the touch event to move between pages .

Comment: It sounds like the view pager has consumed the onTouchEvent already. You might have to override ViewPager to not consume the touch event and pass it to the child. (override onInterceptTouchEvent)

Comment: You may want to look this too http://blog.svpino.com/2011/08/disabling-pagingswiping-on-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement [onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), determine if the touch is within the horizontal scroll section of your WebView, and then call [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) on the parent of the WebView (assuming that is the ViewPager).

Determining if the touch is within the horizontal scroller may be tricky, but you can probably accomplish that with some JS callbacks that the WebView listens for.

Before all of that, you may want to consider the UX implications of this though.  It may be confusing / disorienting to the user to have horizontal scrolling content in a horizontal scrolling view.